# Jetty http/2 add ServerSessionListener to server

Tags: jetty, http2

i am using embedded Jetty to implement HTTP/2. At the moment i am trying to add a ServerSessionListener (from: org.eclipse.jetty.http2.api.Session.Listener.Adapter) to my Server.

i tried to add it to the Context and Server via: addEventListener with no success.

Maybe someone can give me a hint about what i am doing wrong..

I want to add a session Listener to my HTTP2 Connection to track the connected Sessions (Clients) and their connection duration.

Regards!

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing and what you want to achieve. Post your code.

Comment: I want to achive that i can store the session id, and can see what a user requested / responsed over this sessionid.

Comment: HTTP/2 does not have a concept of session id, so it's still not clear what "requested / responsed over this sessionid" means.

Comment: i thought that every clients connects does this over a session. i just want to recive "Session openened" or "Session Closed" from my server over the Listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an implementation of `Connection.Listener` as a bean to the connector itself, for example:

```
http2Connector.addBean(new Connection.Listener()
{
    public void onOpened(Connection connection) { ... }

    public void onClosed(Connection connection) { ... }
});
```

Alternatively you can add the `Connection.Listener` as a bean to the `ConnectionFactory`.

In both cases, every time a connection is created, the listener is added to the connection and will be invoked when the connection opens and when it closes.

You can use Jetty's `ConnectorStatistics` class that already gathers a number of statistics about connections and already implements `Connection.Listener`.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question. Is it possible to add this Listener to a HTTP2Client aswell?

Comment: Currently no, but I filed [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/542) to implement it. Contributions are welcome.